# How to sum two matrices in Scala?

Tags: scala, matrix, functor, scalaz

Suppose I define type `Matrix` as `Vector[Vector[Int]]` and sum two matrices like this:

```
type Matrix = Vector[Vector[Int]]

val addup: (Matrix, Matrix) => Matrix = (_, _).zipped map ((_, _).zipped map (_ + _))
```

Is there a library, which provides a generic `zipped map` so I can simplify `addup` ?

Comment: Use https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze

Comment: I would like to avoid dependencies except `scalaz/cats`

Comment: Use this for inspiration if you are familiar with scalaz and cats: http://www2.math.ou.edu/~dmccullough/teaching/f06-6833/haskell/matrix.pdf